# Add control dependency after operations are created?

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to create a control dependency between two ops after they've both been created? I realize that with `tf.control_dependencies` it's possible to make one op wait on another before executing, but the dependent op has to be created within the `tf.control_dependencies` context. I'd like to construct the two ops independently first and then add the dependency.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why you need to do this? (I wonder if there's another way to accomplish what you're trying to do without the post-hoc dependency setting.)

Comment: It's purely aesthetic. The flow of my code is messier if I have to create an op later on, but that option appears to be the lesser of two evils.

Comment: Phew, good.  (As noted below by mrry, the only ways I can think of to do it involve, e.g., writing out the graph, modifying the pbtxt, and then reading it back in, and I'm glad to not have to go there. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might be a disappointing answer, but it is not possible to add a control dependency (or any other input) to a TensorFlow `Operation` after it has been created. Tensors and operations are *immutable* once they have been created.

One possibility would be to **clone** the op that should run second, in the appropriate control dependencies context. Let's say that you have two `Operation` objects, `op_first` and `op_second`, and you want `op_first` to run before `op_second`:

```
def first_before_second(op_first, op_second):
    """Sequence `op_first` before `op_second`.

    Given two operations, returns a pair of operations with the same behavior
    except that the first returned operation will execute before the second
    returned operation.
    """
    with tf.control_dependencies([op_first]):
        g = tf.get_default_graph()
        op_second_clone = g.create_op(op_second.type,
                                      [in_t for in_t in op_second.inputs],
                                      [out_t.dtype for out_t in op_second.outputs],
                                      attrs=op_second.node_def.attr,
                                      op_def=op_second.op_def)

    return op_first, op_second_clone
```

A similar modification could make this deal with `Tensor` objects as well, but that's left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

While not possible in general, you can slightly modify an existing `op` to enforce dependencies. For example, you can add zero to a tensor:

`def first_before_second_num(op_first, op_second):
   with tf.control_dependencies([op_first]):
       op_second += 0
   return op_second`

If you have a `NoOp` like a `train_step`, then you might want to group it with another `NoOp`:

`def first_before_second_noop(op_first, op_second):
   with tf.control_dependencies([op_first]):
       op_second tf.group(op_second, tf.no_op())
   return op_second`