# Computing the weight-update-ratio in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm searching for a way to compute the [weight-update-ratio](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#ratio) for optimizer steps in Tensorflow. The weight-update-ratio is defined as the update-scale divided by the variable scale in each step and can be used for inspecting network training.

Ideally I want a non-intrusive way to compute it in a single session run, but couldn't accomplish quite what I was looking for. Since the update-scale and parameter scale are independent of the train step, one needs to add explicit dependencies to the graph in order to graph variable-scale before and after the update step. Unfortunately, it seems that in TF dependencies can only be defined for [new nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206445/add-control-dependency-after-operations-are-created), which further complicates the issue.

So far, the best I've come up with is a context manager for definining the necessary operations. Its used as follows

```
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e0)
grads = tf.gradients(loss, tf.trainable_variables())
grads = list(zip(grads, tf.trainable_variables()))

with compute_weight_update_ratio('wur') as wur:
    train = opt.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=grads)

# ...
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(wur.ratio)
```

The full code of `compute_weight_update_ratio` can be found below. What bugs me is that in the current state the weight-update-ratio (at least `norm_before`) is computed with every training step, but for performance reason I'd rather prefer to do it selectively (e.g only when summaries are computed).

Any ideas on how to improve?

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def compute_weight_update_ratio(name, var_scope=None):
    '''Injects training to compute weight-update-ratio.

    The weight-update-ratio is computed as the update scale divided
    by the variable scale before the update and should be somewhere in the 
    range 1e-2 or 1e-3.

    Params
    ------
    name : str
        Operation name

    Kwargs
    ------
    var_scope : str, optional
        Name selection of variables to compute weight-update-ration for. Defaults to all. Regex supported.
    '''

    class WeightUpdateRatio:
        def __init__(self):
            self.num_train = len(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAIN_OP))
            self.variables = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope=var_scope)
            self.norm_before = tf.norm(self.variables, name='norm_before')

        def compute_ratio(self,):
            train_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAIN_OP)
            assert len(train_ops) > self.num_train, 'Missing training op'

            with tf.control_dependencies(train_ops[self.num_train:]):
                self.norm_after = tf.norm(self.variables, name='norm_after')

            absdiff = tf.abs(tf.subtract(self.norm_after, self.norm_before), name='absdiff')
            self.ratio = tf.divide(absdiff, self.norm_before, name=name)

    with tf.name_scope(name) as scope:
        try:
            wur = WeightUpdateRatio()

            with tf.control_dependencies([wur.norm_before]):
                yield wur
        finally:
            wur.compute_ratio()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about performance too much. Tensorflow only executes the subgraph necessary to produce the output.

So, in your training loop, if `wur.ratio` is not called during an iteration, none of the extra nodes created to compute it will be executed.

Comment: That is partly correct I guess, as there is an explicit dependency of norm_before (see control_depencies towards end of code listing) on the train step, so that would get executed anyway, right?

Comment: @ChristophHeindl You're right, this one will be executed each time `train` is called. You could probably put this dependency into `compute_ratio`, to enforce it only when needed.

Comment: that's what I thought too, but unfortunately I don't see way that could be done, as dependencies can only be  from existing nodes to nodes to be created ( the train step - see link in original question). In `compute_ratio` the train step is already created, so its too late for that :(

Comment: @ChristophHeindl I see, it seems I got the gist of your question only now. There could be ways to avoid this extra `norm` but they would be less friendly than your solution (and intrusive), either creating extra training ops, or calling `norm` twice during successive iterations. The question is, is it worthwhile? Variables are generally small (compared to data) and I doubt an extra `norm` operation per iteration adds much to the computational burden. That is something you could measure first before deciding to optimize this computation away.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Will wait for potential other ideas and then either answer my self accept your answer.